# LoganSquare and Salut libraries - Android Wifip2p

Tags: android, wifip2p

I try to using salut librari (wifip2p library) for Android.

All work fine, discover devices, connect host, connect clients...
But when I need send a message, I have a problem.

I follow Salut tutorial: [Salut](https://github.com/markrjr/Salut)

I send a message, and in console say me tha tthe message is received.

```
09-13 13:21:58.633 21798-21906/app.ingenia.marse.ingeniamarse D/Salut: Listening for service data...
09-13 13:21:58.643 21798-21986/app.ingenia.marse.ingeniamarse V/Salut: A device is sending data...
09-13 13:21:58.675 21798-21986/app.ingenia.marse.ingeniamarse D/Salut: Successfully received data.
```

But I can't read the received message.

**The sender function:**

```
public void sendData(){

    Message myMessage = new Message();
    myMessage.description = "See you on the other side!";

    network.sendToAllDevices(myMessage, new SalutCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            Log.e(TAG, "Oh no! The data failed to send.");
        }
    });

}
```

Where I **received data**:

```
@Override
public void onDataReceived(Object data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Received network data.");
    try
    {
        Message newMessage = LoganSquare.parse((Message)data, Message.class);
        Log.d(TAG, newMessage.description);  //See you on the other side!
        //Do other stuff with data.
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse network data.");
    }
}
```

The code don't excecute the log received network data. And I need to change one line:

```
Message newMessage = LoganSquare.parse((Message)data, Message.class);
//to
 Message newMessage = LoganSquare.parse(String.valueOf((Message)data), Message.class);
```

And the **Message.class**:

```
@JsonObject
public class Message{

    /*
     * Annotate a field that you want sent with the @JsonField marker.
     */
    @JsonField
    public String description;

    /*
     * Note that since this field isn't annotated as a
     * @JsonField, LoganSquare will ignore it when parsing
     * and serializing this class.
     */
    public int nonJsonField;


    @OnJsonParseComplete
    void onParseComplete() {
        Log.d("PARSED", "onParseComplete: PARSED!!");
    }

    /*
     * Optional callback method to do something before your
     * object serializes.
     */
    @OnPreJsonSerialize
    void onPreSerialize() {
        Log.d("SERIALIZED", "onParseComplete: SERIALIZED!!");
    }

}
```

The two logs in message.class nor they have executed

Answer (score 0):

It is because according to documentation, onDataRecieve() is not executed as data.isEmpty() returns true. Check what i mean from [here](https://github.com/markrjr/Salut/blob/master/src/main/java/com/peak/salut/BackgroundDataJob.java).

Comment: I have exactly the same issue than this guy (WIngenia) and I don´t understand your answer, actually your answer is not a real solution. I don´t know what do you mean when data.isEmpty return true because I am sending info from the host to the client.